# dateTimePicker ValueChange

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `DateTimePicker` and every time I want the event `dtpJournalDate.ValueChanged` is being called.

My problem is that, when I click the dropdown arrow, the event `dtpJournalDate.ValueChange` is already executing even if I have not chosen a new date yet and after I have chosen a date, it would again execute the `ValueChange` event. I only want the event `ValueChange` execute after I have chosen a date?

```
Private Sub dtpJournalDate_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpParametersDate.ValueChanged
   'Some Codes to do when changing the date
End Sub
```

Comment: try `OnCloseUp ` event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.oncloseup(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DavidR System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was a web forms question by mistake.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Use `CloseUp` event handler as @Damith mentioned

```
Private Sub dtpJournalDate_CloseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpParametersDate.CloseUp
    'Some Codes to do when changing the date
End Sub
```

But this event will not firing if user input date information manually(writing straight to `DateTimePicker`'s textbox.
Then you can add `KeyPress` event handler and run your code after user press `Enter`-button:

```
Private Sub dtpJournalDate_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dtpParametersDate.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter) Then
        'Run your code with new date information
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change event handler in onCloseUp event

```
Private Sub MyDatetimePicker_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ValueChanged
        Me.OnCloseUp(e)
        'Do what ever change you want, when instance is created.
End Sub
```